# char[] в Character[]

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, char, java-8

Как перевести массив char[] к его оболочке Character[] для дальнейшей сортировки в обратном порядке?
Делаю по аналогии как с int -> Integer:

```
int[] array = {...};
Integer[] newArray  = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
Arrays.sort(newArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Но с char так не работает:

```
Character[] newArray = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().toArray(Character[]::new);
Arrays.sort(newArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, для примитивов `char` есть такая проблема. 
Можно например так её решить:

```
char[] array = {'a','c','b'};
Character[] newArray = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> array[i])
    .toArray(Character[]::new);
Arrays.sort(newArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

> c, b, a

Comment: А можно как-то пояснить, чем такая проблема вызвана?

Comment: В смысле, почему это не реализовали в API? Не могу ответить, так как сам не знаю, просто на практике сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой.

Comment: @Qwertiy разработчики решили, что это большинству не надо, и ограничились стримами для `int`, `long` и `double`.

Comment: А, понял. Я опять забыл, что в джаве генерики не работают с примитивами...

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать преобразование в строку и метод `chars`:

```
char[] array = new char[] {'a', 'c', 'b'};
Character[] newArray = new String(array).chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i).toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `ArrayUtills`

```
Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(array);
Arrays.sort(charObjectArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```